# Deriving closest approach as a function of impact parameter

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, scattering, plasma-physics, kinetic-theory

I've come across this expression for the distance of closest approach:
$$r_{min}=\frac{bcos[{\frac{\theta}{2}]}}{1-sin[{\frac{\theta}{2}]}}$$
where the impact parameter is :$$b=\frac{Z_{1}Z_{2}ke^{2}}{mv_{0}^{2}}cot\frac{\theta}{2}$$which is :$$=\frac{Z_{1}Z_{2}ke^{2}}{2KE}\sqrt{{\frac{1+cos{\theta}}{1-cos{\theta}}}}$$
However, I cannot put together where it comes from, other than that it is obviously related to the geometry of Coulomb scattering.
I am not necessarily looking for a full derivation, mostly wondering how this expression is a product of scattering geometry and Coulombic repulsion.

Reference from : [this](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Nuclear/rutsca2.html) HyperPhysics page on the Rutherford experiment.

Edit: included the formula for impact parameter, also from HyperPhysics. 
This isn't homework, but I suppose counts as an exercise?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what's being asked here?  Are the OP and the bounty creator trying to understand the origin of the form of the impact parameter?  Are they asking about how the impact parameter is derived (even though the OP says they aren't looking for that but then say several things afterwards suggesting they are)?

Comment: Just for reference for a radial potential, closest approach radius as a function of impact parameter can be derived entirely from conservation of energy and angular momentum.

The radial velocity at the point of closest approach is zero, which lets you use the conservation laws to solve for angular velocity and radius.

Comment: @honeste_vivere As the bounty creator, I'm looking for the origin of the $r_{min}$. I do understand and know from where the impact parameter is derived, but I have been unable to understand from where the $r_{min}$ comes from.

Answer (score 1):

Let $v_{min}$ is the velocity of a projectile at the moment of closest approach to a target. Due to energy and angular momentum conservation, there are the relations
$$
KE = \frac{m}2 v_{min}^2 + \frac{Z_1 Z_2 e^2 k}{r_{min}}
$$
and
$$
r_{min}v_{min} = b\sqrt{\frac{2KE}{m}}.
$$
From the later one we have
$$
\frac{m}2 v_{min}^2 = KE\frac{b^2}{r_{min}^2}.
$$
Then the former gives the following equation for $1/r_{min}$:
$$
KE = KE\frac{b^2}{r_{min}^2} + \frac{Z_1Z_2e^2k}{r_{min}}.
$$
From the last equation
$$
\frac1{r_{min}} = \frac1{b}\left(-\frac{Z_1Z_2e^2k}{2KE}\frac1{b} + \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{Z_1Z_2e^2k}{2EK}\frac1{b}\right)^2}\right) =
$$
$$
=\frac1{b}\left(-\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos(\theta)}{1+\cos{\theta}}} + \sqrt{1+\frac{1-\cos(\theta)}{1+\cos{\theta}}}\right) = \frac1{b}\frac{1-\sin(\theta/2)}{\cos(\theta/2)}.
$$
This is just what we need to derive.